# Is the manga Yozakura Quartet still translated?

Tags: yozakura-quartet

I'm thinking about starting the manga Yozakura Quartet and looked the releases up. I noticed that in Japan, 14 volumes are released, the last one in October. The English list only lists volumes 1 to 5 and I've been wondering whether the translation is still ongoing because I don't want to start a manga that I can't finish.

Is the English translation of *Yozakura Quartet* still ongoing?

Source of the releases: http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=8801&page=28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. After the original US publisher, Del Ray, [ceased publishing](http://www.siliconera.com/2010/10/09/del-rey-to-cease-publishing-manga-restore-licenses-to-kodansha-usa/) manga, Kodansha USA took up all Kodansha licenses, but they [mentioned](http://kodanshacomics.tumblr.com/post/49378524386/is-there-any-chance-to-see-suzuka-get-completed) that it [did not have any plans](http://kodanshacomics.tumblr.com/post/49386683538/so-not-continuing-any-del-rey-series-at-all-thats) to resuce any other titles.